# SSL Certificate webmin

Tags: ssl, webmin

I'm currenty working with webmin And it is a great program. I creaties And connected An SSL certificate tot mydomain.nl And when I go to that link IT has the green Kock. But when I go to mydomain.nl:10000 (webmin control panel) IT has the red locker with An warning

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed some step while installing SSL Certificate on your webmin url. You should re-check the steps which you have followed.

Below are the steps which I followed to secure webmin control  panel and I am able to access it with https://

```
Step 1: Login to Webmin site using https://your-domain-name.com:10000

Step 2: Once you log in, you will see Webmin Dashboard.

Step 3: Click on your server’s hostname

Step 4: Once you click on  it, you will see one window named Hostname and DNS client page

Step 5: Enter a fully qualified domain name into hostname field and click on the Save button.

Step 6: Go to Webmin configuration and select SSL Encryption.

Step 7: Once you click on the SSL Encryption option, you will get one window. Enter the following details
and click on the Request Certificate button at the botton of the screen.

Hostname for Certificate: Make sure you have typed correct fully Qualified Domain name.

Website root directory for validation file: Enter /var/www/html/

Months between automatic renewal: Select the radio button to the left of the input box and type 1 in the input box

Click on the request Certificate option to issue ssl certificate.

Step 8: Once you click on it, you will have to wait for a minute. You will get a confirmation message on the screen.

Step 9: Restart Webmin 

Reload the Webmin page and you browser will show valid certificate.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by going to webmain and select you domain have SSL
service configuration --> Manage SSL Certificate 
Then copy it to Webmin

[image]

[image]